# Creating an executable file at Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, build, macos-big-sur

I am relatively new in programming using the C-language. So to lay it all out, I am still kind of clueless of what is happening. Now, may I ask why I can't seem to create an exe file and run the code?

Actually, the first time I tried executing it, it worked. However, to make sure that it is working, I repeated it and then it didn't work anymore.

To make things clearer:

- I use Mac
- Mac OS Big Sur
- In this particular case, gcc is the compiler
- I also tried using Code::Blocks also prior to this; however, I have similar issues -- after I built and ran my first "hello world" program, it didn't run the same program anymore after it. I also tried reinstalling it, but it still has the same issues.

I'm really frustrated that this is happening because I cannot move on to the next lessons in my class. :(

Thank you very much! I hope someone would help a newbie here. :))

Comment: If you are using gcc as the compiler then it may be creating a file called a.out that is an executable. This is the default name gcc gives executables. If you are doing this on the command line than running gcc -o filename.exe filename.c will change the default behavior and name it filename.exe instead. If you are not using the command line I'm not sure how to do this, but there should be some way.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering. Yes, I am doing this on terminal (the command line interface). What can I do though? Thank you :))

Comment: What is the command you use / button you press to make the file?

Answer (score 0):

Gcc by default names executables `a.out`. So you can check if that file has been created by running `ls a.out` and looking through the results.

If it has been made, you can run it from the command line with `./a.out`.

If you want to name the executables something else, then when calling gcc, add the flag `-o` followed by the name you want. E.g. if you want filename.c to compile to filename.exe, then you would write `gcc -o filename.exe filename.c`. Then you can run it from the command line with `./filename.exe`. I think if you give it the .exe file extension you should also be able to run it by clicking it in the Windows file explorer.

Comment: My professor actually gave the same comment work-around a while ago. However, it still doesn't work, even after trying it again right now. :(

Comment: Can you tell if it is compiling without errors? Maybe there's a mistake in your code which is preventing compilation.

Comment: Hello, the same was said by my professor a while ago. He asked me to try if the code was working on Xcode. I also cleaned the project on Xcode and it ran. Then using the same code from the VSC then the cleaned one from Xcode, I tried running it back again at VSC; unfortunately, it yielded the same result. :(